# scoria sand: What is it good for?

Tags: soil, soil-amendment

I have sifted scoria to isolate the coarse sand from the fine one.

I have the coarse ingredient which I will use it mainly for my succulents. However, I am left with a bag full of fine scoria sand, which is as fine as dune sand and even has lots of dust in it.

My question is - What is this good for? Can I use it to plant something, or shall I throw it and just use the coarse one? Is it a good idea to use it for the garden, to enrich the soil with minerals?